# Htaccess create redirects for folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running Apache 2.4.9. I have this rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?url=$0 [L]
```

It works flawlessly, except in this particular case:
When calling `/myfolder` (if the "myfolder" folder actually exists), Apache will return a http301 to the url: `/myfolder?url=myfolder`

I'm really not sure what could cause this redirection.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: This code does not perform a redirect. The redirect might be a cache, since you are reporting a 301 redirect. Clear your browser cache and see if this fixes the problem. If this does not fix the problem, identify what is causing this redirect. Code in `index.php` maybe?

Comment: This is definitly what causes the redirect. If I modify "url" to "url2", the redirect changes. 
Also, I directly try this using curl or wget. So this is notlinked to a caching issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you would likely get away with adding an additional condition before all others. Now it says "if the filename is not a directory and not a file" or "if the filename is not a directory and ends with css/js", which works fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?url=$0 [L]
```

This is an internal rewrite, so it does not perform redirects of any kind. The redirect comes likely from a `header(..)` in your index.php file.